# Convert a Ruby object to an IO-like object with a JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm on a Rails application, building a service to read Google Spreadsheets, using the [Google Drive Ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem.

As per the [gem documentation](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/blob/7f0a9a21d0ab31261bf226f35b00f0b7be6fa1d0/lib/google_drive/session.rb#L80) it looks like I could provide an IO-like object with the JSON instead of the JSON file directly as an argument.

Problem is I'm not quite sure how to build said object from my existing, think something like:

```rb
my_object = { "property": "value" }
```

How do I turn this `my_object` into an IO-like object with the JSON inside? I'm not even sure I quite understand what it refers to with the IO-like object. Is this even possible? Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could turn that hash into a JSON string and then make a StringIO out of it.

```
io = StringIO.new(JSON.generate(my_object))
method_that_accepts_io(io)
```

> it looks like I could provide an IO-like object with the JSON instead of the JSON file directly as an argument.

Not sure what you meant by that, but if you have a file with JSON in it, and you can't pass just the filename (so the callee opens and reads it by itself), you can open the file and pass that.

```
io = File.open("my_file.json")  
method_that_accepts_io(io)
```

> I'm not even sure I quite understand what it refers to with the IO-like object.

This means an object that walks and quacks like [IO](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html) (has methods `#read`, `#lines`, `#bytes` and others)